# How to make the app wait till a json request is completed

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am building a contacts app for my company. Each time a search is executed, the app will check whether that particular device is activated(through Json url) to access that data. If it is not, then it will take the user to another activity that asks for an activation code. Now the problem is: From the main activity it will proceed to the results display activity only if the activation flag(integer) is set. But because the activation check takes some time, my flag is not set soon enough because of which the app never goes to the results display. Even when the activation check is successful, by the time the flag is set the code has crossed the part were I call the results activity.

So, How can I make the activation flag check wait till the activation check is completed?

Please excuse me if I have am not making sense. This is a complex scenario.

Comment: what i do is set an indeterminate and uncancelable progress dialog till then :)

Comment: lemme try that out right now...

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a ProgressDialog.
2. Override onBackPressed and return false to stop closing the dialog when back pressed.
3. Make the HTTP request.
4. After receiving JSON data close the ProgressDialog.